# Setting values to object dynamically (dynamic property/type)

Tags: java, android, reflection, dynamic-cast

I'm trying to create JSON to Object mapper. Its main idea is that "user" defines a dictionary where keys are JSON attributes and values are Objects property names. So how does it work (so far):

1. Get value from JSON (var jsonValue)
2. Get property type from getter (var methodType)
3. Create setter method and insert value from json

Only problem is that I can't cast jsonValue into object dynamically. I have to check what's the object type (methodType) and then cast it differently for String, Long, Integer and so on. Can I somehow cast it dynamically?

```
    private Cookbook createCookbook(JsonObject jsonCookbook) {
    //Cookbook to return
    Cookbook cookbook = new Cookbook();

    Enumeration<String> e = mappingDictionary.keys();
    while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
        //get JSON value
        String mappingKey = e.nextElement();
        JsonElement json = jsonCookbook.get(mappingKey);
        String jsonValue = json.getAsString();

        //set JSON value to property
        String mappingValue = mappingDictionary.get(mappingKey);

        //reflection
        try {
            //get type of the getter
            String getMethodName = "get" + mappingValue; 
            Method getMethod = cookbook.getClass().getMethod(getMethodName, null);
            Class<?> methodType = getMethod.getReturnType(); 

            //set methods
            String setMethodName = "set" + mappingValue;
            Method setMethod = cookbook.getClass().getMethod(setMethodName, methodType);

            //set value to property
            /* DONT WANT TO DO IT LIKE THIS, THIS IS MY PROBLEM */
            if (methodType.equals(String.class))
                setMethod.invoke(cookbook, jsonValue);
            if (methodType.equals(Long.class))
                setMethod.invoke(cookbook, Long.valueOf(jsonValue));

        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }           
    }

    return cookbook;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create non-primitive objects of unknown type in runtime using reflection (as You used) and .newInstance() method.

You can't create primitive types in this way, for example, if You take look in standart JDK serialization implementation (writeObject() of ObjectWriter), You see the switch with 8 cases.

Comment: I'm OK with creating a new class with methodType.newInstance(); but I don't know how to convert my String (jsonValue) to newly created object.

Comment: See sources of ObjectInputStream; method "private Object readArray" could contain answer to your question

Comment: I've checked ObjectInputStream but as I see it they are also detecting type and then parsing individually for every type.. I guess that's the way to go.. I can't find any "smarter" way